# How do I get my app to go to this custom view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, hyperlink

I have this custom action in my videos controller:

```
def upvoted_songs
  @votes = current_user.videos_votes.where("value = 1")
  @videos = @votes.videos.page(params[:page]).per(15)
end
```

this is my routes:

```
resources :videos do
    member do
      put 'topic_update'
      get 'upvoted_songs'
    end
end
```

And this link in my videos index view:

```
<%= link_to "Upvoted Songs", videos_path, :action => "upvoted_songs", :class => "upvoted_songs chosen_home_option" %>
```

and a view file called videos/upvoted_songs.html.erb.

Why doesn't the link direct to the upvoted_songs.html.erb view but rather stay on the video index view?

UPDATE:

These is my routes.rb:

```
root :to => "videos#index"
resources :video_votes
resources :videos do
    resources :comments
    member do
      put 'topic_update', :on => :member
      get 'upvoted_songs', :on => :collection, :as => 'upvoted'
    end
end
resources :comment_titles
resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :genres
resources :topics
resources :topicables
resource :session
```

I initially get this error:

```
ArgumentError

can't use member outside resource(s) scope
```

Then after refreshing the page, I get this error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Videos#index

Showing /rubyprograms/dreamstill/app/views/videos/_video.html.erb where line #22 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :id=>#<Video id: 485, title: "I'm Ready For You", description: nil, embed_code: nil, thumbnail_url: nil, released: nil, user_id: 57, created_at: "2011-04-02 08:47:36", updated_at: "2011-04-09 22:42:48", video_url: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wy86KNtOjVg", video_votes_count: 0, vote_sum: 3, rank_sum: 28927.724512>, :controller=>"videos"}

22: <%= link_to video.title, video_path(video), :class => "normal" %>
```

Comment: just curious: @votes = current_user.videos_votes.where("value = 1") shouldn't that be > 1? :P

Comment: no because I want to retrieve all the videos that the user has upvoted, and in my app that is when the vote's value is 1  :)

Comment: i see, i thought you wanted to get all the upvoted votes. but woudn't a boolean be better than 1? just asking again :)

Comment: hmm i'm not sure how that would work, the reason I have 1 is that if it is an upvote, value = 1, if it's a downvote, the value is -1, and if the user decides to remove his vote, the value is 0. Then summing up the total vote value is easy.

Comment: ohh nice, gotta remember that sometime then if i ever have to make that feature

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what routes are available for use in your app use `rake routes` on the command line in the root directory of the app. You should see a line that refers to `upvoted_songs`.

Then use it like so:

```
<%= link_to "Upvoted Songs", upvoted_songs_video_path(video), :class => "upvoted_songs chosen_home_option" %>
```

Since you have it has a *member* route the url helper will take a video object (or id) and generate a url that looks something like: `/videos/7/upvoted_songs`

However, your code suggests that you might be doing something that does not rely on a single video object, and wouldn't need that in the URL either. So you would want to change that route from a *member* route to a *collection* route. The URL would then end up looking something like `/videos/upvoted_songs` and you wouldn't be passing it a video object.

Hope this helps :)

**PART 2**

Remove the member block:

```
resources :videos do
  resources :comments
  put 'topic_update', :on => :member
  get 'upvoted_songs', :on => :collection, :as => 'upvoted'
end
```

Comment: thanks, how do I change it to a collection route? that's what I want.

Comment: check out the answer below by coreyward he has it there

Comment: @Justin I posted an example for you. You can double check the routing guide when you forget this stuff, too. It's pretty comprehensive. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @ctcherry any idea what this error from coreyward's code means? `ArgumentError

can't use member outside resource(s) scope`

Comment: Did you type `member` or `:member` ? It needs the colon if you may have missed it.

Comment: I typed `:member` I'm getting some wierd errors in my app though

Comment: I updated the question details with more details on my errors.

Comment: Remove the member block, see PART 2 on this answer

Answer (score 2):

You are linking to `videos_path`, which is a helper for "videos#index".

As ctcherry explained, your current route is using a member route and not a collection. The following is more what you're looking for:

```
resources :videos do
  put 'topic_update', :on => :member
  get 'upvoted_songs', :on => :collection, :as => 'upvoted'
end
```

Then you can use `upvoted_videos_path` in place of just `videos_path`.

Comment: thanks. your code threw this error for me: `ArgumentError

can't use member outside resource(s) scope` what does this mean?

Comment: Make sure you have the call to `put 'topic_update', :on => :member` inside the block being passed to `resources`. And like ctcherry mentioned in response to this, make sure you didn't miss the colon.

Comment: I updated the question details with more details on my errors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have an id. Do a rake routes | grep upvoted and see what your route should look like.

it's probably something like `upvoted_songs_video_path(video)`